# how to call a controller from xslt in anchor tag

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, xslt

I get an error in anchor tag where I call `controller(blog),action name(index)`. I want my URL to look like blog/travels/1.
 Here 'travels' is the name of parent and '1' is the child id.I want to call a controller from xslt with respect to parent name and id.

This is my .xslt page:

```
   <xsl:for-each select="Parent">
           <div class="grid-col-3">
             <ul>
               <h4>
                 <a href='@Url.Action("Index","Blog", new{{@ParentName}/{current()/@Id}}'>
               <xsl:value-of select="@ParentName"></xsl:value-of>
               </a></h4>
               <xsl:for-each select="/BlogCategories/BlogCategory[@ParentID = current()/@Id]">
                 <!--<xsl:if test="@ParentID=$Id">-->
                 <li class="lis">
                   <a href="{@Name}/{current()/@ID}">
                     <xsl:value-of select="@Name"></xsl:value-of>
                   </a>
                 </li>
                 <!--</xsl:if>-->
               </xsl:for-each>
             </ul>
           </div>
         </xsl:for-each>
```

I want to call this blog controller

```
         public ActionResult addblogxml(string actiontype)
    {
        if(actiontype== "Submit")
        {
            var blog = _api.GetAllBlogCategory().ToList();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFiles/BlogCategory.xml"));
            writer.WriteLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>");   
            writer.WriteLine(blog[0]);
            writer.Close();
            var xDocument = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFiles/BlogCategory.xml"));
            string xml = xDocument.ToString();
            ViewBag.BlogCategoryXML = xml;
        }
        return View("~/Areas/BMS/Views/CategoryBlog/addblogxml.cshtml");
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The right curly brace in an attribute value template '@Url.Action("Index","Blog", new{{@ParentName}/{current()/@Id}}' outside an expression must be doubled.

Comment: It may have just been an error in copying, but you're missing a closing parenthesis:  `href='@Url.Action("Index","Blog", new{{@ParentName}/{current()/@Id}}'` should be `href='@Url.Action("Index","Blog", new{{@ParentName}/{current()/@Id}})'`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve what you're looking for is to make a change in your RoutConfig.cs.  Inside the `RegisterRoutes` method, add the following route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Blog",
      url: "Blog/{parent}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index", parent = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );

   ...
   // Default/other routes below
}
```

Then you only need to use:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Index","Blog", new{ @parent = @ParentName, @id = @Id})'>
   <xsl:value-of select="@ParentName"></xsl:value-of>
</a>
```

Comment: hey i do the same thing what u tell me but it get error as     Expected token '}', found ','.

Comment: Where are you getting that error?  In the route config or the `<a>` tag?

Comment: i am getting this error in <a> tag as Expected token '}', found ','.

Comment: Try `<a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Blog", new RouteValueDictionary(new { @parent = @ParentName, @id = @Id } ))'>`

Comment: No idea then, it works for me.  Check the parameters `Url.Action` is expecting and do some basic troubleshooting from there.  I'm using MVC5 and have no issues with that line.

Comment: Blog", new{@parent =@ParentName  -->,<-- @id =@Id})

Comment: Did you try by passing in a `new RouteValueDictionary` (see my comment above).  `Url.Action` has various overloads, the two you want are `Action(string actionName, stringcontrollerName, object routeValues)` and/or `Action(string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)`.  The third parameter in the answer I posted creates a new object, the one in my comments creates a new RouteValueDictionary.  Check your `Url.Action` method and see what it is expecting for its third parameter if these aren't working for you.

Comment: <a href='@Url.Action("Index","Blog", new{@parent =@ParentName ,@id =@Id})'><xsl:value-of select="@ParentName"></xsl:value-of></a></h4>

Comment: i am getting a syntax error  near to anchor tag.the error is Expected token '}', found ','.
...Blog", new{@parent =@ParentName  -->,<-- @id =@Id})

Comment: i change in route config as routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Blog",
              url: "Blog/{parent}/{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "addblogxml", parent = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );

Comment: hey when i remove only this part , id from anchor tag .no error.but when i click on parent it will not read the url correctly.